# Нужен аналог pagePixels для кластеризованной метки

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

У некластеризованной метки на карте в событии 
    objectManager.objects.events.add('click', function (e) {...})
можно получить значение свойства e._sourceEvent.originalEvent.pagePixels.

Как получить значение координат кластеризованной метки на карте в событии 
    objectManager.clusters.events.add('balloonopen', function (e) {...}) ?

Понятно, что кластер это не конкретный географический объект? Но метка "с цифрой" - вполне себе конкретный объект javascript, кок получить его pagePixels?

Comment: а зачем? какую задачу вы хотите так решить? _sourceEvent.originalEvent - недокументированная внутренняя сущность под капотом API, она может непредсказуемо меняться, потому что это не часть публичных интерфейсов

Comment: Для описания подробностей метки создан собственный всплывающий div блок. По событию balloonopen этот блок открывается. Но метка с цифрой после автоматической центровки оказывается под этим блоком, я бы хотел подвинуть ее вверх, оттолкнувшись от значения pagePixels[1].

Comment: для этого в API есть готовые балуны, которые сами привязываются к метке, вы можете их полностью кастомизировать, создав свой макет

Comment: Готовые балуны не устраивают заказчика. Пришлось изобретать свой велосипед и решать ряд казалось бы простых задач заново. И все же можно ли поработать с кластерной меткой как с JS объектом и получить ее координаты на странице?

Comment: вы можете как угодно кастомизировать готовые балуны. использовать внутренние методы API не стоит, они поменяются в любой момент

Comment: Reni, добрый день. Решил подойти к задаче с другой стороны. Подскажите, пжл, если я имею географические координаты кластерной метки gX и gY - каким методом я могу сместить карту, чтобы эта кластерная метка оказалась отцентрована по 1/2 ширины экрана, а ее высота составила бы 1/4 экрана (отсчитывая сверху)? (Кластерная метра в ObjectManager).